# IonInput and IonLabel is not side by side

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am having this code

```
<ion-list>

    <ion-list-header>
    Input list:
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let att of anArray; let idx = index">
          <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{att.labelA}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].valueA" clearInput></ion-input>

          <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{att.labelB}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].valueB" clearInput></ion-input>

          <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{att.labelC}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].valueC" clearInput></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But why does the output become

> A1
>
> B1
>
> C1
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---

I wanted to be like

> A1
>
> ---
>
> B1
>
> ---
>
> C1
>
> ---

Thankyou.

If I create a div tag inside ion-item, it’s position is perfect but data can’t be entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have wrapped them in a single `ion-item` which makes sets them in a single row.

You need to set as separate `ion-item` for each label and input. You can use `ng-container` for the for loop if you don't need additional divs in the HTML.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let att of anArray; let idx = index">
<ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{att.labelA}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].valueA" clearInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{att.labelB}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].valueB" clearInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{att.labelC}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].valueC" clearInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ng-container>
```